# From jQuery to Webpack, NPM, Angular, SASS, Gulp, ES6, etc

Tags: angularjs, npm, webpack, vue.js, gulp

I am not sure how to ask this to be honest, but I'll give it a shot.

So for many years I had worked with HTML, CSS, jQuery and PHP. Without a tertiary education I taught myself web development many years ago and was eventually able to earn a living and kind of get out of a bad situation and build a slightly better life. In essence, I got into web development out of a need rather than a passion. However, I got into it and learnt to enjoy it.

The problem, however, is that web development has evolved quite a bit in the last few years, or lets say, the new technologies have become more prominent and widely adopted. Why this is an issue is it seemed to have become rather advanced, and in my inexperience opinion, more complicated.

For example, almost all web projects out there, specifically on github, seem to be built with and/or dependent on the following technologies (grouped by association): Nodejs (and NPM), Gulp/Grunt, WebPack, SASS/LESS, ES6/Babel, Angular/Vue/React, Typescript, linting, Templating, Unit testing, CommonJS, AMD, RequireJS, to name a few.

I believe I have waited a bit too long to decide to actually catch up a bit, and it has felt rather overwhelming to say the least. I found it so much easier to just include a js script into and HTML file and hit the ground running, than to face these ever accumulating technologies.

I find it very difficult to actually get a grip on all the above mentioned technologies because it seems that so many projects use so many of these technologies at once which just makes it so difficult to really get on board with the new age web development.

To prepare my question, consider this: I never studied coding or programming and have been self taught from the beginning, for the sake of making a living, and I pretty much am the kind of developer the internet would probably like to see less of considering how I would pretty much make Frankenstein main.js files that heavily relied upon jQuery and the many plugins out their. The guilt of having polluted the internet like that still eats me up inside.

My question is this...

WHERE DO I START?

How can I make these new ideas and technologies just click for me? How can I finally "get" it? Learning everything at once feels impossible but I am not even sure where to begin if I want to take it one step at a time.

I have learnt some basics. I have learnt how to setup and work with NPM based projects. I have gotten a bit familiar with Gulp and Grunt for the likes of SASS and Babel. That alone burnt me out :P . Then I gave Webpack a try and I just started losing track and I am now feeling quite frustrated not quite knowing what to do to keep on track.

Could any of you suggest almost a pathway to get there? Like an order of what to learn in which order for me to be able to piece all of this together? So that I myself can setup and build more modern applications?

For example, perhaps an order would be this: Nodejs (npm), Gulp, Vue, React. Not even sure if that makes sense. But the idea is that surely there is a journey a dedicated developer could take to keep on track and not get lost because of the overwhelming techniques that make up the new web.

Perhaps this journey can involve specific apps or projects that I should build, like a mini Node server, then a basic Grunt task, then ES6 compiling, etc. As long as I can always keep the connection between all these tools and techniques clear.

My hopes is that I can get into the swing of things and really join the online community of new age developers.

Any feedback, links, videos, references, snippets are much appreciated. And thanks for the excitement, wonder and mentorship that you all bring as a collective.

Comment: "Where do I start?" https://codeburst.io/the-2018-web-developer-roadmap-826b1b806e8d

Comment: Thanks @Gonzalo.- Looks like an awesome guide. Going through it right now!

Comment: this is offtopic for stackoverflow, even though the people on here could give you great advice.     I see a lot of self taught devs use pluralsight / edX / coursea  etc with their video based courses.   Seems to work well for many.    Also worth watching people on things like https://twitch.tv/communities/programming